# Windows tool which can create a 3D text or logo in batch or command line?

Tags: windows, graphics, 3d-graphics

I want to create text in 3D or create logos but wanted to automate the process to create a large number of them by passing in the text. Are there any tools for Windows that can work in any kind of non manual method like in a batch file, command line or through an API?

Answer (score 1):

image magick can do this: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/

Comment: I also recommend imagemagick.  Used it for years.  Very powerful and it really makes scripted images easy. Also check out http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/3Dtext/index.php and http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fonts/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Actions** in **Adobe Photoshop**.

a tutorial [here](http://www.creativemac.com/2002/04_apr/tutorials/psbatch.htm).
[This tutorial is for Mac. The procedure is same if you are on Windows instead]

Comment: scripts might just be what you need. Do check this out: http://www.kirupa.com/motiongraphics/ps_scripting.htm